# Qt App works fine on MacOSX, Access Violation on Windows

Tags: windows, qt, exception, qt4, access-violation

So I've stumbled into a problem that I am not able to solve for a while. I'm writing a Qt application in C++, and have been developing on MacOSX, which it runs fine on. However, as I am testing the code in windows I'm running into the following access violation when I close OR cancel QDialog child that I have:

`Unhandled exception at 0x5ce6b1ea (QtGuid4.dll) in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefefa.`

Debugging this, I see that it crashes after a lot of Qt api calls, eventually making its way down to QWindowSurface_Raster.cpp. Here is the Qt library code that it crashes on:

```
#endif
{
    QPoint wOffset = qt_qwidget_data(widget)->wrect.topLeft();

    HDC widget_dc = widget->getDC();

    QRect wbr = br.translated(-wOffset);
    BitBlt(widget_dc, wbr.x(), wbr.y(), wbr.width(), wbr.height(),
/*CRASH HERE!*/   d->image->hdc, br.x() + offset.x(), br.y() + offset.y(), SRCCOPY);
        widget->releaseDC(widget_dc);
    }
```

And lastly here is my code where I call the qdialog:

```
void MainWindow::prefDialog()
{
        prefD = new PreferenceDialog(this);
        prefD->exec();
} /* crashes here, after I hit cancel/ok on dialog and it leaves exec */
```

PreferenceDialog.h:

```
class PreferenceDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    PreferenceDialog(QWidget *parent);
.....
```

PreferenceDialog.c

```
PreferenceDialog::PreferenceDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent)
{
....
connect(okayButton, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(okayClicked()));
connect(addKeyButton, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(addClicked()));
connect(cancelButton, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(cancelClicked()));
    ....
```

I can show you my PreferenceDialog code, or any other code, but I think it'll just bloat things up. PreferenceDialog doesn't do much other than shown, and I dont override any function like exec(), etc. The stack trace is pretty bloated too so I wont post for now, its simply a bunch of Qtguid4.dll calls after exec() finishes, (about 10) until it gets to that crash in QWindowRaster.

Let me know if any other information is needed though. I'm pretty new at Qt so having a hard time figuring this out, any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: You might try my ["noisy debug hook for Qt"](http://hostilefork.com/2012/10/02/the-essential-noisy-debug-hook-for-qt/).  I've seen it give some feedback about problems that led to HDC-related stuff in the past...

Comment: It did not help with my specific problem, but I could certainly use it in other areas, thanks for the info

Comment: Well, it was worth a try...and if you leave it in I bet it will save you some time in the near future.  I put it in every project.  Moving forward...even if it involves a few files, can you make a minimal case?  Just keep removing buttons and lines of code from the program until the crash goes away.  Then add it back and repeat the process.  You'll either find the problem or have something so short we can compile it and reproduce it ourselves!   http://sscce.org/

Comment: Ah thanks for the advice.. not sure why I didn't think of that instead of trying to plow through all that code. It ended up being that I was calling destroy(); instead of close() when canceling the dialog box, so it must have been calling a null pointer somewhere in exec since I destroyed it... Not sure why it didn't do that on Mac, hard bug to track down, Thanks!

Also, new to StackOverflow.. I'm assuming I'm supposed to answer my own question with this info..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was calling QDialog::destroy() to close the window instead of QDialog::close(). This caused a null pointer exception when Qt was finishing QDialog::exec() and caused a crash on Windows. Changing the call to close() fixed the problem.

Thanks HostileFork for the advice